# apt and apt-get in Dockerfile returning error

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a Docker image of Cassandra. Cassandra requires Java. I have added line to install java. In my Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install default-jre
COPY apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar.gz .
RUN tar -xzf apache-cassandra-3.11.6-bin.tar.gz 
RUN chmod -R 777 apache-cassandra-3.11.6
RUN ls
RUN echo $PATH
RUN echo $PWD
RUN apt update

#RUN apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
#RUN java -version
WORKDIR apache-cassandra-3.11.6
RUN ls
ENV CASSANDRA_HOME=/apache-cassandra-3.11.6
ENV PATH=$PATH:$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin
RUN echo $PATH
RUN ls
WORKDIR apache-cassandra-3.11.6/bin
RUN ls
CMD ["cassandra","-f"]
```

I am getting error in apt-get update and apt. How can I fix this?

```
C:\Users\manuc\Documents\manu\cassandra_image_test>docker build -f CassandraImageDockerFile.txt -t manucassandra .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  184.8MB
Step 1/19 : FROM ubuntu:20.04
 ---> 74435f89ab78
Step 2/19 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in b395852c8e6b
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [33.4 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [177 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1275 kB]
Reading package lists...
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1d 13h 27min 45s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1d 12h 39min 24s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1d 12h 39min 54s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: How about trying this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096930/sudo-apt-update-error-release-file-is-not-yet-valid? Restart your docker host for timezone reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with your timezone. Please restart your Docker host.

Comment: Do you mean restart docker daemon or my laptop? I am on Windows10 Home

Comment: Restart Docker and it should fix this system clock error.

Comment: had to restart the laptop

Answer (score 1):

**Docker Desktop:**

You can manually restart it using UI.

**Docker machine:**

```sh
$ docker-machine restart <DOCKER-MACHINE-NAME>
```

**Podman:**

```
$ podman restart <PODMAN-MACHINE-NAME>
```